# Is there any way to get query progress (e.g. 75%) for ActiveRecord / Rails / Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rails-activerecord

Is there any way to get an estimate of query progress (e.g. 75%) for ActiveRecord / Rails / Postgres? Or if I were to switch off ActiveRecord, is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this with *Postgres*.

It can be done with, say, *Hive* queries in a *Hadoop* cluster, especially when there are a large number of mappers and reducers, because it's a partitioned query and when pieces of it finish, it can have some idea of its progress (although that progress isn't always smooth, since not all data is necessarily distributed equally).

In *Postgres*, since there's only a single query, there are (currently) no partitions to finish piecemeal and report progress. The only way I know of to ballpark progress, if you **really** want to know, is to `strace` the *postgres* process running your query and see what files it's reading. Due to the layout of tables on disk, this can provide some sense of progress based on what it's reading. However, it's an indirect relationship, to be sure, to a completion percentage, and generally not worth the hassle, IMO.

The best bet, in general, is to ensure your statistics are up to date in the involved tables, and then look at the query plan, and try to infer the relative complexity / potential execution time based on what that says.